# How to get started with computational research after a PhD in Physics?

Tags: machine-learning, career

I have a PhD in theoretical physics, where I had worked on mathematical models of hydrodynamics around compact objects. I have basic knowledge of programming in C/C++ and Python. Currently, I am more interested in computational work, particularly on numerical simulations and machine learning algorithms for data mining in astrophysics.

I need advice regarding how to get started. I tried to get an answer on the internet but owing to the huge amount of information available online I couldn't get my answer, rather I became more confused. Could someone please help me to know the computational and mathematical skills that I require to get started? Also, I want to know if there are any resources (courses or textbooks) that can guide me to acquire the basic knowledge.

Comment: You don't start post-doc research on your own, do you ? First look for open opportunities.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I need to start a postdoc under any professor. But since I don't already have the required computational skills, no research group would hire me unless I have prior knowledge. So I need to gain knowledge of the basic computational stuffs.

Comment: "no research group would hire me": how do you know ? Don't be so pessimistic. Is your PhD of no value ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust During my PhD I worked only on mathematical models. However, in every advertisement of a postdoc, they clearly mention that the candidate should have computational skills in the form of published papers. I can work on similar lines as my PhD work, but I am now more interested in computational works. I just need to have the basic knowledge, e.g., learning python programming, understanding ML algorithms etc.

Comment: Are you really going to publish as an independent researched until you meet these criteria ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust It will not be possible to publish independently. Rather, if I have the basic computational knowledge, there are chances of getting hired in a research group. I have experience of using Mathematica, but I have never worked with simulations.

Comment: You contradict yourself "computational skills in the form of published papers".